# Is it possible to modify dimensions of revit model through design automation api? if yes how?

Tags: forge, autodesk-designautomation

currently im trying to modify my model from viewer with help of design automation api, it is possible to get properties of revit file but how to modify those properties and view back to the viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course - possible workflow would be:

- Create a plugin to modify your model - see this code sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/tree/master/updateRVTParam)
- Bundle your plugin to upload to Forge and define an activity for execution - see tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/)
- Load the model into Viewer after translating it with Model Derivative
- Collect the data/parameter from user input and/or model properties/metadata
- Call a workitem with the parameters and execute the plugin, can upload the modified output as [versioned items](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) to track changes
- Use [webhooks](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/dm.version.added/) to get notified of new version being added and trigger a translation of it, or you can upload the output to your own app and trigger upload and translation with your own workflow
- Load the modified model back into Viewer

See [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels) for our official tutorial on Design Automation.